# why form submit data in Google Analytics and how to remove it?

Tags: google-analytics

I wonder why GA is tracking this link:

> /de/shop/pizza.html?tx_pizza_basket[action]=addToCart&tx_pizza_basket[controller]=Basket&cHash=fae9b7812f842f543hgf0ac374e9a978ca0

This URL (domain is removed here so it's not the full path) opens the basket with some pizzas added to it :)

I wonder why GA is tracking this exact path and how to stop GA from tracking this sort of form submit URLs.

Here is my GA Code:

```
# JavaScript für Google Analytics

temp.google.analytics = TEXT
temp.google.analytics.value (

<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-87654123-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

)
```

Regards,
M.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Google Analytics records the value of `document.location.href` when it is executed. If you don't wish to record the URL parameters for this page, you have 2 options:

1. Create a set of advanced filters for the reporting view that excludes parameters `tx_pizza_basket[action]` and `tx_pizza_basket[controller]`. Additionally set your view's `Exclude URL Parameters` setting to include `cHash`
2. For this particular page, change `ga('send', 'pageview')` to `ga('send','pageview', document.location.pathname)`